# Ruby 2d array to csv?

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv

There is an array, how correctly to deduce in csv a file?

```
arr1 = [["A","B"], ["C","D"], ["E","F"], ["G","H"]]
```

Expected result in csv:

```
A,B
C,D
E,F
G,H
```

I do so:

```
out_file = File.open('file.csv', 'w')
arr1.each_index do |inx|
  arr1[inx].each do |val|
    out_file.puts val
  end
end
```

But, Prints all in one column:

```
A
B
C
D
..
```

If you output to the console through `p val`, then in each value is / r:

```
"A\r"
"B\r"
"C\r"
"D\r"
```

What do I do wrong?

Edit:
[result csv Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50p2O.png)
[result csv Vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNp7A.png)

Comment: `File.write('file.csv', [["A","B"], ["C","D"], ["E","F"], ["G","H"]].map { |e| e.join(",") }.join($/))`.

Comment: @Andrey Deineko , Output all values in one cell

Comment: @DenisDerevyankin I don't think that `Output all values in one cell` aligns with the expected result you have provided.

Comment: @mudasobwa Again in one column, but now with (",") in front

Comment: I do not follow. The code I provided produces exactly what you have requested.

Comment: @mudasobwa https://i.stack.imgur.com/50p2O.png

Comment: I have no idea what this GUI tool is for, to check CSV one usually opens the produced file in any text editor, like `vim`, or `emacs`.

Comment: @mudasobwa This is Excel, Tell me, what kind of apostrophe ^M https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNp7A.png

Comment: Homebrewing a CSV is bound to end in tears. Just use `CSV` module. Make sure to use the options to adjust for your own Excel (Excel CSV parsing IIRC tends to be locale-sensitive, with some cultures using `,` and some prefering `;`) Also make sure the newline separator is set to Windows. E.g. `CSV.open(..., col_sep: ";", row_sep: "\r\n")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *are not* writing to file.

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open('file.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  arr1.each { |ar| csv << ar }
end
```

Comment: `<<': undefined method `map' for #<String:0x00000002405ea0>

Comment: @DenisDerevyankin I edited the answer, there's no longer `map` method

Comment: This doesn't work. `CSV#<<` takes either a `CSV::Row` or an `Array`, but you are passing a `String`. `CSV#<<` will then try to `map` the elements to CSV, but will `raise` a `NoMethodError: undefined method \`map' for "A, B":String`.

Comment: Work, but one column
`A
,B
,C
,D`
Can be used for each value of `chomp` ?

Comment: @DenisDerevyankin I do not understand what your comment means.

Comment: @Andrey Deineko I post the picture, the result of the work of your code. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?(

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is to simply **print** out the CSV string, then you can do it like this:

```rb
csv_string = CSV.generate { |csv| array2d.each { |row| csv << row }
```

Here's a worked example:

```rb
> # array2d contains the raw data
> csv_string = CSV.generate { |csv| array2d.each { |row| csv << row } }
> puts csv_string
5014,"John O""Neill",4295,1,Finance Plus
314,"Thomas, Duncan",436,2,Finance Plus
1930,Fraser Smith,436,12,Finance Plus
5057,Fred McDonald,436,12,Finance Plus
```

Note that it handles double-quotes and commas inside strings.

See: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Answer (score 0):

It works,

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open('file.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  arr1.each { |ar| csv << ar }
end
```

But it was necessary to finish in front of it:

```
 arr1.each_index do |inx|
    arr1[inx].each do |val|
    val.chop!    
  end
 end
```

To delete a line break `\r`

and it works:

```
File.write('file.csv', [["A","B"], ["C","D"], ["E","F"], ["G","H"]].map { |e| e.join(",") }.join($/))
```